# What is the use of ! in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the use of `!` in rails?

Especially in this line: From HArtl tutorial

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do 
    content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
    user.each { |user| user.microposts.create!( content: content )}
end
```

Basically this is creating tweets/microposts for 6 users.

I am really wondering why need to use `!`

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-create-21

Comment: The `create!` method is slightly different than the `create` method. `!` is not an operator in this context. It's part of the method name. The documentation that @SebastianPalma linked describes the `create!` method. For comparison, check the description of the `create` method right before it.

Comment: Is the Hartl tutorial still the go-to reference? That seems like something worth fixing.

Comment: hello guys, i appreciate you for answering. do you happen to know why you would wanna be returned with "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid" rather than "nil" ?

and when do you want to be returned with "nil"? 

apologize for my question, i am teaching my self on how to rails. i am still new and i want to understand the bits.

Comment: This is really a pure-Ruby question. Rails simply follows the Ruby convention of when to end method names with a question mark or exclamation mark.

Comment: My fading memory tells me there is at least one core method whose name ends with an explanation mark for a reason other than it mutates its receiver. Can anyone think of one?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The Rails Console `reload!` method just has one because it's *exciting* to reload.

Comment: The following returns a list of the 68 core bang methods in Ruby v2.6.3: `ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).with_object([]) { |mod,a| mod.instance_methods(false).select { |meth| meth.to_s[-1] == '!' }.each { |meth| a << "#{mod}\##{meth.to_s}" } } #=>[..., "Hash#merge!", "Array#rotate!", ...]`. @tadman, I only recognize two of those that do not change their receiver: [Kernal#exit!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-exit-21) (and possibly `exit!` methods for a few other modules) and [BasicObject#!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-21).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `exit!` exits the process without running the exit handlers, which is "more surprising" than `exit` which does run them, just like if the program had exited on its own. `!` is a red herring, it's the unary prefix `!` operator, i.e. `!foo == foo.!()`.

Comment: @Jörg, as you say, `!foo` is candy for `foo.!`, but since `foo = true; foo.! #=> false; foo => true`, the method `BasicObject#!`, whose name ends with an exclamation mark, does not mutate its receiver. No? What you say about `exit!` is true, but it does not mutate it's receiver, which is all I claimed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that in Ruby a trailing `!` or `?` are allowed on method names and become *part of the method name*, not a modifier added on. `x` and `x!` and `x?` are three completely different methods.

In Ruby the convention is to add `!` to methods that make *in-place modifications*, that is they modify the object in fundamental ways. An example of this is `String#gsub` which returns a copy, and `String#gsub!` which modifies the string in-place.

In Rails this has been ported over to mean that as well as situations where the method *will raise an exception on failure* instead of returning `nil`. This is best illustrated here:

```
Record.find_by(id: 10) # => Can return nil if not found
Record.find_by!(id: 10) # => Can raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

Note that this is not always the case, as methods like `find` will raise exceptions even without the `!`. It's purely an informational component built into the method name and does not guarantee that it will or won't raise exceptions.

*Update*:

The reason for using exceptions is to make flow-control easier. If you're constantly testing for `nil`, you end up with highly paranoid code that looks like this:

```
def update
  if (user.save)
    if (purchase.save)
      if (email.sent?)
        redirect_to(success_path)
      else
        render(template: 'invalid_email')
      end
    else
      render(template: 'edit')
    end
  else
    render(template: 'edit')
  end
end
```

In other words, you always need to be looking over your shoulder to be sure nothing bad is happening. With exceptions it looks like this:

```
def update
  user.save!
  purchase.save!
  email.send!

  redirect_to(success_path)

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render(template: 'edit')
rescue SomeMailer::EmailNotSent
  render(template: 'invalid_email')
end
```

Where you can see the flow is a lot easier to understand. It describes "exceptional situations" as being less likely to occur so they don't clutter up the main code.

Comment: The note also applies for Ruby itself. Some methods don't have a `!` variant and still mutate the object in-place. For example [`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-delete)

Comment: hi tadman, appreciate you for answering. additional question, why would you wanna be returned with "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" rather than "nil"? and when would you want to be returned with "nil" ?

Comment: @eric I've added an example at the end as to how this plays out in practice.

Comment: I suggest you delete "Update:" (the word, not the added text). Also, perhaps worth noting that many banged methods return `nil` when no change is made, which is sometimes be used to advantage. Perhaps make @eric's point as well.